# TortoiseHG Workbench resolving conflicts Windows 8 elevation issue

Tags: tortoisehg

When attempting to use "Tool Resolve" within the TortoiseHG Workbench on a file using Windows 8

I get the following error

```
abort: The requested operation requires elevation
```

The auto generated command looks like this

```
% hg resolve --repository "C:\MecurialRepositories\Test" -- "C:\MecurialRepositories\Test\Web.config"
```

Not really sure why this is the case, it works with TortoiseGit on the same machine.  I've tried to uninstall/reinstall and registry clean but it looks like there are additional permissions I need to set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diff tool wouldn't work for me from TortoiseHG on Windows 8 unless I ran TortoiseHG using "run as administrator". I found that updating KDiff to version 0.9.98 removed the need for privilege elevation.